# Auto refresh Sharepoint-linked Tables in Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables linked with sharepoint lists. And I have a form in access db, each time when the form loads the table which is linked to sharepoint list should refresh automatically.

Is there ant way to do this in vba code?
I'm using

```
 Application.DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CurrentDb.TableDefs("TableName").RefreshLink` (replace `TableName` with your actual table name).