# OpenRecordset doesn't retrieve latest values from Sharepoint Online list

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-online

```
Dim DB As DAO.Database: Set DB = CurrentDb
Dim Log As DAO.Recordset
        
Set Log = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table WHERE NOT IsNull(Field) ORDER BY Id DESC")
```

On the first run, this query retrieves the correct values.
On subsequent runs, the same initial values are returned, even if the actual record has changed.

For example:

1. Released = `01/01/2000`
2. Recordset returns `01/01/2000`
3. Released = `12/06/2001`
4. Recordset returns `01/01/2000`
5. Open linked table or restart access
6. Recordset returns `12/06/2001`

I'm assuming there's some caching going on, but I can't find how to ignore it and always fetch the latest records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh your Sharepoint linked table:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("TableName").RefreshLink
```

Reference to this:

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23429699/14456737)