# How do I link my Access tables to a Microsoft List, so that changes made to the List shows in the Access table?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an Access database with many tables and relationships and I have queries and reports that I run on those Access tables. I want to export the tables to Lists so that I can change information in the Lists and that updates the Access database so I can still use my queries and reports? I've already exported all my tables to Lists, just not sure how to link them.

I've tried exporting a table from Access to Lists but when I updated the List and refreshed the Access table there were no changes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Export the lists to 'what'?

Comment: @peter I want to export my Access tables to Microsoft Lists

Comment: Yes, but Microsoft lists in what technology; web based on desktop. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There is no _List_ object in Access, _Listbox_ is the closest, but it makes no sense in this context. Use a form in DataSheet view bound to the table to edit table data with no "export".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How did you perform "refresh"? I expect the export is a one-way action and suspect have to set a link to list (if it's even possible), as in SharePoint - 
not a local table in Access. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429699/auto-refresh-sharepoint-linked-tables-in-access-2010